# Not expand listbox with scrollbar

Tags: python, listbox, scrollbar

Im trying create listbox with scrollbar but I found two inconveniences:

1. Scrollbar appear even if listox is empty.
2. Listbox expand and I want not that occupy total width of screen, only width=50

My code:

```
text=tkinter.Listbox(root,height=10,width=50)
text.bindtags((text, root, "all"))
for i in range(20):
    text.insert(i,i)

scrl = Scrollbar(text, command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrl.set)
scrl.pack(anchor='center', side = RIGHT, expand=FALSE, fill=BOTH, ipadx=0, ipady=0)
text.pack(anchor='nw',side=TOP, expand=FALSE,padx=10,pady=10,fill=BOTH,ipadx=0,ipady=20)
print (int(text.winfo_width()))
```

If I change Fill to Y, the result is wrong: http://s6.postimg.org/x0e445ym9/Sin_t_tulo.png

Thanks in advance.